# How to add a second screen to rapsi 4 whitout raspi crashing

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, screen, crash

Hi I recently bought this [screen](https://www.amazon.ca/Monitor-1024X600-Touchscreen-Display-Raspberry/dp/B08KXXKPW9/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2GBVKKJ8IINDF&keywords=new%21%207inch%20ips%201024x600&qid=1652019209&sprefix=new%207inch%20ips%201024x600%2Caps%2C250&sr=8-1) on amazon and every time I connect it my raspi 4 freeze after 5-10min

On the user manual it instruct to add this to the config.txt in /boot

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=7
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 6 0 0 0
```

How can I stop my rpi from crashing ?

Comment: check the power supply output voltage when everything is powered on ... check again when the RPi crashes

Comment: the power supply is the canakit 5.1v 3.5a

Comment: that is not checking the output voltage

Comment: Power your screen separately from the Pi.

Comment: the screen is not powered by the pi and the pi still freeze

Comment: Edit your question with this info.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Do you actually have 2 screens connected at the same time - your title/question are not clear.

Comment: I installed raspberry pi os 64bit. I have my main screen and I want to add the touch screen as a second screen be when I do the pi freeze 5-10min after